# Show tag summaries on Careers 2.0 skill tags to assist recruiters

Tags: feature-request, jobs, tag-wiki, popups

Not necessarily something I need as a user, but something I see as valuable to folks looking to hire via Careers 2.0.

Similar to how tag summaries are shown when searched for during the tagging of a StackOverflow post, why not provide those same tooltips on hover?

Potential benefits I see include:

- Help recruiters / employers who might not be familiar with the technology.
- Gives candidates a leg-up who may have similar or complex experience in an unfamiliar technology by highlighting what the technology does.
- Encourage candidates to use more accurate and meaningful tags
- Encourage the expansion of the tag library with technologies that might not be discussed often on SO.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with this idea (and it's *not* a bad idea!) is that the tags shown on careers are links, but they don't link to the same destination tags do on SO.

That is:

- On SO, the tag [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) links to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript`.
- On Careers, if I'm searching for employees, the `javascript` link goes to `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:userID+[javascript]`. That is, if I'm looking at [Jason Punyon's CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/candidate-search#!profiles/1179/Jason-Punyon), the `javascript` tag link goes to
  `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:6212+[javascript]`.
- On Careers, if I'm searching for jobs, the `javascript` link goes to `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/javascript`.

Having all three display the same popover would, to me, imply that they all go to the tag wiki—and on Careers, they don't.